# Snakify lesson 6 question 3, I need a breakdown of how and why this code works

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on Snakify and have come across an issue regarding question 3 "The power of two" in while loops.

The question is:

> For a given integer N, find the greatest integer x where 2x is less than or equal to N. Print the exponent value and the result of the expression 2x.
> Don't use the operation **.

I made my own code that worked and then checked it against the recommended solution and found that it was different.

My code:

```
n=int(input())
x=1
y=0
while x*2<=n:
  y+=1
  x*=2
print(y, x)
```

The developer's solution:

```
n=int(input())
x=1
y=0
while x*2<=n:
  y, x=y+1, x*2
print(y, x)
```

I tried to figure out how the developer's solution worked myself by deleting sections of the code and couldn't figure out why I got the error `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object` after deleting `x*2` in line 5. What is the purpose of having x*2 there, it's not doing anything?

I don't understand why I need y to be in front of `x=y+1` in line 5 besides the fact that the computer otherwise makes x a tuple not understanding that it's working with a series of commands instead of one. It feels redundant to call for y because to me it looks like it's not doing anything even though it's doing something.

I also don't understand what's happening with `x=y+1`, what's its purpose in the code? I know that you have to somehow make x worth more so that the loop doesn't go on infinitely but y doesn't increase in value with each loop and therefore x would remain the same plus 1?

I'm also wondering why it's the "better"/recommended solution. Does it have something to do with efficiency and if so, how and why is it more efficient?

Thank you for taking the time to read this and I hope nothing is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Glad to answer on your question. I have check your description.

First, your code and developer's code is the same. I suggested you to refer the priority of python operator.

In this code `y, x=y+1, x*2`, `=` operator is lower than `,` operator.

So, this code works like that `y=y+1, x=x*2`.

And I suggested you to use Math module and more efficient method as below.

```
import math

n = int(input())
x = math.floor(math.sqrt(n))

print(x, x*x)
```

Hope to be helpful for you. Thanks and best regards.